# Changing the title of the Answers add answer form

Tags: 7

I want to change "Your answer" in the add answer form of the Answers module so that it says "Give [user who asked question] your answer".

Here is a snippet of code from `answers.module` that defines the value

```
// Add the form to the question page.
        $node->content['new_answer_form'] = $answer_form;
        $node->content['new_answer_form']['#weight'] = 150;
        $node->content['new_answer_form']['new_answer_form_title'] = array(
          '#theme' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'h2',
          '#attributes' => array('class' => 'new-answer-form-title'),
          '#value' => t('Your answer'),
          '#weight' => -100,
        );
```

I tried changing it to:

```
// Add the form to the question page.
        $node->content['new_answer_form'] = $answer_form;
        $node->content['new_answer_form']['#weight'] = 150;
        $node->content['new_answer_form']['new_answer_form_title'] = array(
          '#theme' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'h2',
          '#attributes' => array('class' => 'new-answer-form-title'),
          '#value' => t('Give ', $author, 'your answer'),
          '#weight' => -100,
        );
```

Not surprisingly, this didn't work. I'm not sure which variable to use for $author, and other changes, so that the username of the person who asked the question appears there.

Disclaimer: I apologize if the question is off, I work for a non-profit organization that isn't a tech company and am just trying to build us a new website but have a gluten for punishment and an interest in getting back in to the tech field. Thanks for your patience.

Edit: I created a helper module for customizations to other modules.

Comment: You should never change module files directly. Instead, you can create a new module and implement _alter hooks_ to override output from other modules. Second, that is not how the `t()` function works... I suggest you read [its documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7.x) first and update your question so it includes valid code.

Comment: Okay. Is `new_answer_form_title` a hook so I could `drupal_alter('new_answer_form_title', 'new_answer_form_title_new');` with `$new_answer_form_title_new = array (some stuff);`?

Comment: Please double check what you put up here. There is no `$new_answer_form_title_new` in `drupal_alter('new_answer_form_title', 'new_answer_form_title_new');` so that does not make sense. The clearer you are, the better we can help. Do not rush it, better to read it over and make sure is correct :)

Comment: That question was good, buy you were mixing up variables and strings in your example, which in turn confused me... ;) I hope the below answer gets you somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the node object, you can find its author via `$node->uid`. Then load the account and wrap it in [`format_username()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_username/7.x):

```
$uid = $node->uid;
$account = user_load($uid);
$account_name = format_username($account);
```

The hook you need depends on the function in which your snippet was found. In your case it is in `hook_node_view`, so you need [`hook_node_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7.x)

From there it is as simple as redefining the value. Something like this:

```
MODULENAME_node_view_alter(&$build) {
  $node = &$build['#node'];

  $new_title = t("Give @author your answer", array('@author' => $account_name));

  $node->content['new_answer_form']['new_answer_form_title']['#value'] = $new_title.
}
```